# I'm getting the error Error: Expected identifier but got '(' on line 44 of my solidity smart contract in vs code

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a constructor function in my solidity contract file and on line 44 it's giving me an error in vs code Error: Expected identifier but got '('

Here's my contract so far

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

// INTERNAL IMPORT FOR NFT OPENZIPLINE
import "@openzeppelin/conracts/utils/Counters.sol"; // using as a counter which will keep track of id and counter
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol"; // Using ERC721 standard
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    uint256 listingPrice = 0.0025 ether;

    address payable owner;
    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idMarketItem;

    struct MarketItem {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 price;
        bool sold;
    }

    event idMarketItemCreated(
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address seller,
        address owner,
        uint256 price,
        bool sold
    );

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "only owner of the marketplace can change the listing price"
        );
        _;
    }

    constructor() ERC721("NFT Metaverse Token", "MYNFT") {
        owner == payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function updateListingPrice(uint256 _listingPrice)
        public
        payable
        onlyOwner
    {
        listingPrice = _listingPrice;
    }
}
```

I tried just giving an identifier and I thought it would fix the error but it didn't

Answer (score 0):

You use the equal sign `==` for an assignment `=`. Try the following:

```
constructor() ERC721("NFT Metaverse Token", "MYNFT") {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry; turns out this vs code extension was the problem it's called everscale I thought it would just format the contract for me but it also had linting so I just uninstalled it.